# How to make a basic Forum Thread on my website?

Tags: php

How to make a basic Forum Thread on my website ?
Like they click it shows the thread without going to a new page and what not.
EDIT*** Like the user he clicks something that says Thread or a Programming* and it shows all the posts and they may view that post as if it were on a whole new page without the Programming and thread just the post.

Comment: Can you be MUCH more specific about what you're asking for?

Comment: Man, this post is nightmare. :)
Maybe one of CMS is all you need?

Answer (score 0):

You wont be able to do this PHP only...

You can do this with JavaScript though I prefer JQuery as it makes dealing with JavaScript easier. This is a great tutorial on getting started with JQuery which covers show/hide effects (which is what you want to look at to achieve the functionality you've described.)

http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:Getting_Started_with_jQuery

Good Luck!